# Android Altbeacon Causing Scan Scheduled Tasks

Tags: android, bluetooth, altbeacon

I am using the range notifier in the altbeacon library to range for beacons for 30 seconds. The range notifier is in the Application class and doesnt have bootstrap notifier or beaconconsumer implemented. The program when ran in the foreground produces the code below, it should never reach the background.

Why is this happening if the application is running in the foreground?

About phone: Android 9.0 Google pixel 2
Library version: Altbeacon 2.15.2

```
11-28 16:43:44.052 13258-13258/com.testapp.app W/JobInfo: Requested interval +5m0s0ms for job 208352940 is too small; raising to +15m0s0ms
Requested flex 0 for job 208352940 is too small; raising to +5m0s0ms
 11-28 16:44:24.276 13258-13258/com.testapp.app W/JobInfo: Requested interval +5m0s0ms for job 208352940 is too small; raising to +15m0s0ms
Requested flex 0 for job 208352940 is too small; raising to +5m0s0ms
11-28 16:44:24.332 13258-13258/com.testapp.app W/JobInfo: Requested interval +5m0s0ms for job 208352940 is too small; raising to +15m0s0ms
11-28 16:44:24.426 13258-13258/com.testapp.app W/JobInfo: Requested interval +5m0s0ms for job 208352940 is too small; raising to +15m0s0ms
Requested flex 0 for job 208352940 is too small; raising to +5m0s0ms
11-28 16:44:25.010 13258-13258/com.testapp.app W/JobInfo: Requested interval +5m0s0ms for job 208352940 is too small; raising to +15m0s0ms
Requested flex 0 for job 208352940 is too small; raising to +5m0s0ms
```

Below is the code that i think is relevant to the altbeacon library.

Code context: I have implemented the range notifier and bootstrap notifier in a class that extends Application. The StartRanging method gets called when the Bootstrap notifier methods get called or from the activity that has problems. The activity is called when a user taps on a button from another activity, they can go back to the old activity at any time. Once they go between these two activities the above logs get produced. I only range for 30 seconds and once those 30 seconds are over the stop ranging is called.

Class that extends Application:

Oncreate:

```
    beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);

    //Set the time the app last scanned
    scanningTime = 0;
    backgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);

    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24")); //iBeacon

    Region beaconRegion1 = new Region("Beacon1", Identifier.parse("HidingUUID1"), null, null);
    Region beaconRegion2 = new Region("Beacon2", Identifier.parse("HidingUUID2"), null, null);
    Region beaconRegion3 = new Region("Beacon3", Identifier.parse("HidingUUID3"), null, null);
    Region beaconRegion4 = new Region("Beacon4", Identifier.parse("HidingUUID4"), null, null);
    Region beaconRegion5 = new Region("Beacon5", Identifier.parse("HidingUUID5"), null, null);

    rangingRegion = new Region("RangingRegion", null, null, null);
    regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, beaconRegion1);
    regionBootstrap.addRegion(beaconRegion2);
    regionBootstrap.addRegion(beaconRegion3);
    regionBootstrap.addRegion(beaconRegion4);
    regionBootstrap.addRegion(beaconRegion5);
```

Bootstrap notifier methods:

```
@Override
public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
    beaconRegionEvent = true;
    StartRanging();
}

@Override
public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
    beaconRegionEvent = true;
    StartRanging();
}

@Override
public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int i, Region region) {
    if (i == 1) {
        beaconRegionEvent = true;
        StartRanging();
    }
}
```

StartRanging: Checks if ranging is happening and if not then start ranging.

```
public boolean StartRanging() {

    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (now - scanningTime <= Globals.MAX_RANGING_PERIOD * 1000 && scanningTime != 0) {
        Timber.e("Minimum time since previous scan has not passed");
        return false;
    }
    try {
        beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(rangingRegion);
        Timber.e("Starting Range");

        //Scanning is about to happen so set the scan time
        scanningTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        Timber.e("Unable to initialize ranging");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

    //Add this range notifier to the beacon manager
    if (beaconManager.getRangingNotifiers().size() < 1) {
        beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(this);
    }

    return true;
}
```

StopRanging:

```
public void StopRanging() {
    try {
        //Remove the regions being ranged
        beaconManager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(rangingRegion);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Timber.e("Cant stop ranging  " + e.toString());
    }
    Timber.d("Stopped Beacon Ranging");
}
```

Did RangeBeaconsInRegion

```
@Override
public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (now - scanningTime > Globals.MAX_RANGING_PERIOD * 1000 && scanningTime != 0) {
        StopRanging();
    }

}
```

Activity that scanning too frequently happens in code: Every second this activity is open we call StartRanging method.

Runnable gets called in the onCreate()

```
Runnable ScanTimer = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Timber.d("In Runnable");
        handler.postDelayed(ScanTimer, 1000);

        Timber.d("Checks were good starting ranging");

        App.getInstance().StartRanging();

    }
};
```

Comment: Can you explain why this is not what you expect?  Unless you explicitly stop ranging when your app moves to the background, the library will continue to do so in the background using a scheduled job to accomplish this.

Comment: @davidgyoung, sorry i wasn't clear i meant the scan is on in the foreground for the entire period i never close the application and the app is always on screen.

Comment: Can you please show your code?

Comment: @davidgyoung sorry for the delayed response i have been really busy. I have added the related code to the altbeacon lib to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understand that both beacon monitoring APIs (what is started with RegionBootstrap) and ranging APIs (started with startRangingBeaconsInRegion) require beacon scanning, which is implemented in the library by scheduled jobs to do the scans.

So even though the code stops ranging on a timer, it does not stop monitoring, which continues indefinitely.   This is why the logs show continued jobs being scheduled to fo the scans.   If you want to stop all scanning, you must disable monitoring with `regionBootstrap.disable();`

Comment: Is there a way for me to disable the regionbootstrap when i start the ranging and then re-enable them after the ranging has finished? Also why does it schedule tasks when the activity is closed and not the application?

Comment: Yes, you can call regionBootstrap.disable(); then later regionBootstrap.enable();. If you do not want this background scanning behavior simply switch to using beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInregion(...) and it's equivalent stop method.  The RegionBootstrap is designed precisely for background scanning and app auto launch, hence its name.

Comment: Hi, i can't see regionbootstrap.enable but i can on regionbootstrap.enable.

Comment: Oops, sorry -- yeah, there is no regionBootstrap.enable().  Instead, simply construct a new RegionBootstrap instance the same way you did before.  This will re-enable it.

Comment: Thankyou also is the application meant to schedule scans when changing activity, i noticed it would create more schedules each time i changed activity.

Comment: That is caused by the use of BackgroundPowerSaver.  The library detects when an activity shifts to the background and schedules a background scan, then when the next activity moves to the foreground it schedules a foreground scan.  This is as designed.  If you do not want this behavior, simply don't use BackgroundPowerSaver.